# PostgreSQL query: Using immutable functions to efficiently use session-specific custom options

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Consider the session-specific [customized option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html)

```
SET session what.ever = 'my content';
```

used in a udf

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_whatever() RETURNS text AS $$ SELECT current_setting('what.ever'); $$ IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE sql;
```

Is there a guarantee that `get_whatever` will be evaluated once for each session?

I am aware of the [Function volatility categories](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) and that they imply the answer to be 'no'. However, I wonder whether in this very specific setting the answer might actually be 'yes'.

Context:
I am using custom options as a way to parameterize views by session. While referencing the customized options directly works, it comes with an untenable performance penalty. Moving the option reference to subqueries or CTEs has not improved runtime behavior.

The view definition templates I tried were

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( SELECT current_setting('what.ever') we ) co
  JOIN sometable st ON ( st.st_pk = co.we )
  JOIN ...
     ;
```

and

```
WITH co AS (
    SELECT current_setting('what.ever') we
)
SELECT *
  FROM co
  JOIN sometable st ON ( st.st_pk = co.we )
  JOIN ...
     ;
```

and

```
WITH co AS (
    SELECT get_whatever() we
)
SELECT *
  FROM co
  JOIN sometable st ON ( st.st_pk = co.we )
  JOIN ...
     ;
```

with only the latter exhibiting acceptable performance.

Question applies to PostgreSQL 12 and 15.

Answer (score 3):

If you define that function as `IMMUTABLE`, the PostgreSQL optimizer will evaluate it during query planning, so it will be constant for the whole execution of a statement. If you use it in a prepared statement, it will be constant across all executions of that prepared statement.

However, the function will be evaluated for each statement that uses it. So if a user changes `what.ever`, the function will return a different result. You cannot use it for security purposes, to prevent a user from effectively changing the placeholder parameter.

It is a bad idea to mark functions `IMMUTABLE` if they are not. In the worst case, it can lead to data corruption (for example, if the function is used in an index definition). If you know that your queries never changes the parameter as a side effect, using `STABLE` would be alright.

Comment: Would `STABLE` be more appropriate here?

Comment: As the OP shows, postgres will not be able to optimise calls to `VOLATILE` functions in join conditions or other filter conditions, but it should be able to evaluate it only once and then use an index when it's `STABLE`.